# In istio, route outgoing https traffic to internal http service

Tags: istio

I have a pod with container X and container Y, plus istio sidecars.

I would like that whenever container Y makes a request to a specific external https url https://www.example.com/* this gets routed to the internal container X on port 8080 instead.

How is the https cert validation going to work?

Comment: The external http call from container y how is it getting routed to container x.  is there any routing rule for that?  usually the external call from an container will go to istio sidecar which is there inside the pod and get routed externally.

Answer (score 0):

Well I ended up separating the 2 containers in 2 different pods. I understand that istio is not supposed to work within a pod.